# Comment perdre l'accent québécois?

Tags: prononciation, québec, accents-régionaux

Bon, j'en ai marre des commentaires que je reçois, à propos de mon accent. Comment puis-je m'y prendre pour le perdre?

Comment: Note des modérateurs : merci de limiter les réponses à de vraies réponses. « Ne fais pas ça », ça ne répond pas à la question. Voir [Pseudo-answers are bad](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/259/pseudo-answers-are-bad) sur le [site méta](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Si tu as la volonté de faire un travail sur toi et l'argent pour, prends des cours de dictions avec un professionnel.

Comment: Il ne s'agit pas de le perdre, mais de modérer les accentuations, de limiter les 'les è qui trainent'. Dans le sens franco-canadien, ce sont les points que l'on met en avant pour imiter nos amis proches du St Laurent.

Comment: Ce genre de préjugé déplacé à l'origine des commentaires reçus est fort désagréable. On n'a pas à subir cette forme d'intimidation. On indique à la personne de garder son commentaire pour soi. Souvent le gym aide, même à éviter complètement le commentaire! Il s'agit de régler le problème à la source. Bonne chance!

Answer (score 4):

Je sais que ce n'est pas pareil, mais en tant qu'Américain apprenant le français j'ai amélioré mon accent en écoutant une dictée que je récitais en même temps. En notant la différence de prononciation j'essaie de me corriger. Tu peux même enregistrer ta propre voix pour pouvoir mieux entendre les différences. Bien sûr tout ça prend beaucoup de temps.

Answer (score 3):

Tu pourrais te forcer à parler avec des francophones de France, peut-être ? Je crois que l'accent ne s'oublie pas, mais que tu peux en apprendre un autre, surtout par la pratique et l'environnement.

Answer (score 3):

**Rosetta Stone** est la réponse pour toi. Je vais pas le dire si simplement mais tu peux *facilement* trouver des versions pas *forcément*  payantes de ce software.

Fais juste le niveau 1. Je t'assure qu'il rendra ton accent parfait. Il te dira *non* plusieurs fois à la prononciation, mais quand tu réussis, ca vaut le coup !

Answer (score 2):

1. Si tu habites au Québec c'est impossible, le cerveau humain ne te permettra pas d'être conscient de ton accent et tu n'entendras même pas les subtilités.
2. Si tu habites hors du Québec, que tu ne changes plus de région, et que tu fais des exercices de diction et de chant, et que tu évites d'écouter quoi que ce soit de parlé ou chanté avec un accent québécois, tu vas **peut-être** le perdre après de **nombreuses** années.
3. Tu ne le perdras jamais réellement. Aussitôt qu'une émotion extrême survient, ou que tu subis un accident sérieux avec trauma, les accents que tu as acquis ou perdus peuvent se faire mélanger et remonter à la surface.